# Implement generic timer (periodic event) with Java NIO?

Tags: java, nio

Is it possible to receive a periodic generic event on a NIO Selector in Java? On `boost::asio` I've used a [deadline_timer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/deadline_timer.html) before.

For example, I want to call a function once a second on the same thread the selector is running, independently on the amount of load the active sockets on the selector (except for the special cases like taking more than one second to handle an incoming socket message).

Comment: Yes, it's possible: supply the timeout to the select based on how much time is left before the event. The select will either unblock for data (handle it) or for the timeout (handle it). Rinse and repeat. Or, perhaps better, use one of the over-NIO libraries that supports this such as XNIO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might work:

```
private final BlockingQueue<YourFunction> queue = ...

public void run() {
    while(!queue.isEmpty()) {
        queue.poll().performAction();
    }

    selector.select();

    Iterator<SelectionKey> itr = selector.selectedKeys().iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext()) {
        // etc...
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Timer t = new Timer(name, daemon);
    t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            queue.add(new YourFunction());
            selector.wakeup();
        }
    }, 0, 1000);
}
```